# WebStorm SCSS File Watcher error: invalid executable

Tags: sass, webstorm, file-watcher

After creating a new project in the JetBrains WebStorm IDE, I ran into an error with the SCSS file watcher. It says: **ERROR: invalid executable**, but I don't know what causes that error in the first place.

The *scss file* is nothing special at all, nevertheless the error pops up. Please help me understand what causes that error.

[image]

Comment: *"invalid executable"* Check your File Watcher settings -- ensure that the file that watcher uses (sass compiler) does actually exist.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to specify a valid path to [SASS compiler](https://sass-lang.com/install) in your file watcher settings, **Program** field.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.2/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#install_sass_scss, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.2/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#create_file_watcher

Comment: Thanks for the help. Due to the fact that i've switched from vs code to webstorm just a couple of days ago, I didn't notice the color highlighting of the files, indicating that they are not part of the project somehow. Reopening the project fixed the issue and resolved the file watcher error.